# cp -Tr overwrite behavior

Tags: shell, cp

I'm using GNU coreutils

I have a directory `foo` containing a file `file1` and a directory `bar` containing `file2`.

If I now do a `cp -rT foo bar`, bar will contain both files instead of getting overwriten like the manpage might lead you to believe.

I'd like for ´bar´ only to contain the contents of ´foo´ and not get merged.

Comment: What part of the manual are you referring to? Is this using GNU `cp` from coreutils, or some other implementation of the `cp` command?

Comment: I'm referring to `treat DEST as a normal file`. Normal files get overwritten when you copy over them. This is not the case here.

Comment: the contents of the files are irrelevant. I'm talking about the contents of the directories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU `cp`, the `-T` option is used to ensure that the source directory will not be put *inside* the target directory.  It will not cause to contents of the target directory to be removed.

The info documentation on this (`info '(coreutils)Target directory'`) says (it's using `mv` as an example):

> `-T`
>
> `--no-target-directory`
>
> Do not treat the last operand specially when it is a directory or a
>        symbolic link to a directory.  This can help avoid race conditions
>        in programs that operate in a shared area.  For example, when the
>        command `mv /tmp/source /tmp/dest` succeeds, there is no guarantee
>        that `/tmp/source` was renamed to `/tmp/dest`: it could have been
>        renamed to `/tmp/dest/source` instead, if some other process
>        created `/tmp/dest` as a directory.  However, if `mv -T /tmp/source /tmp/dest` succeeds, there is no question that `/tmp/source` was
>        renamed to `/tmp/dest`.

Note that `mv -T source dest` will fail if `dest` is not empty.

---

To replace the contents of `bar` with that of `foo` in your example, use

```
rm -rf bar
cp -r foo bar
```

or,

```
rsync --archive --delete foo/ bar
```